# How to hide one button on click on another button

Tags: flutter, dart, button, containers, visibility

> I have two button one is show and another is hide.  When i clicked on
> show button that time hide button design should be change and  when i
> click on hide button when hide button come from old design and show
> button design  is   changed.
>
> I have one button visibility and one is visibility gone please help me
> on this.

```
class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  bool canShowButton = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: canShowButton,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    color: AppTheme.orange,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.5),
                      child: Text("Show",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13.0,
                            fontFamily: "Segoe UI Bold",
                            color: AppTheme.white,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: !canShowButton,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: AppTheme.white, border: Border.all(width: 2)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.5),
                      child: Text("Show",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13.0,
                            fontFamily: "Segoe UI Bold",
                            color: AppTheme.orange,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: canShowButton,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      canShowButton = !canShowButton;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    color: AppTheme.orange,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.5),
                      child: Text("Hide",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13.0,
                            fontFamily: "Segoe UI Bold",
                            color: AppTheme.white,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: !canShowButton,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      canShowButton = canShowButton;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: AppTheme.white, border: Border.all(width: 2)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.5),
                      child: Text("Hide",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13.0,
                            fontFamily: "Segoe UI Bold",
                            color: AppTheme.orange,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This question for flutter and dart not html or jquery

Comment: Please add the code you have written and state  what is not working for you.

Comment: try to add some of your code for better understand.

Comment: i don't what you are trying to do. but on your last button u need to change the from " canShowButton = canShowButton;" to " canShowButton = !canShowButton;"

Comment: i have four button with two have hide and two four show

Answer (score 0):

you may use Flag var to show and hide or to change the style of the button

```
 bool isShow=false;

 ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: isShow?Colors.grey:Colors.green,
          ),
   onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
         isShow = !isShow;
           });
    },
   child: Container(
           child: Text(
                   isShow?"Hide":"show",
                   ),
           ),
       );
```

then by checking the flag var `isShow` u can design how you want